# Redirect to an action with double anchors in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I wanted to redirect the user to the same url with double hashes in Ruby On Rails after saving info of that tab.
eg. www.mywebsite.com/user/index#profile#address
In this case, my profile tab has 4 sub tabs (one of them is address) each displayed in the url as second hash. All the four tabs have a common action and I want to redirect back to the same tab from which the user saved his last information. I wrote the following code in my user controller action
 `redirect_to :action => :index, :anchor => "profile#address"`
But what it does is redirect to www.mywebsite.com/user/index#profile%23address and ultimately not opening the same tab where he was before saving the address info.(He is redirected to the first tab which I have set as default)
Please help me in this case.

Comment: You should really have a profile _route_ with controllers. In Rails, index is typically reserved for showing ALL objects belonging to that controller/class. For example, `/users/index` should show a list or table of all users in your DB. If you want to show the profile of a single user, your route should be `/users/:id/show` to keep it Rails-esque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that even a valid URL? I suspect that what rails is doing is correct in terms of whatever RFC governs what a valid url looks like.

If you really want to avoid the encoding of the second hash symbol, then you could try just adding a string to the end:

```
redirect_to "#{index_path}#profile#address"
```

However, this may have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

A URL can only have a single fragment (the `#` part), so what you want to do is not possible and forbidden by e.g. [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-24).  Rails follows that specification and "percent encodes" the second hash sign to keep the resulting URL standards conform.

You'll have to find a different way to encode the information (e.g. parsing the fragment with javascript).